# SQL select part of text

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm looking to store the text of a stored procedure into a variable.
I have the data appearing in a column, but I only want the data within the ALTER.
I'm not that experienced with SQL, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
SELECT ?????????????????????
FROM    sysobjects 
JOIN    sys.sql_modules 
        ON      sysobjects.id = sys.sql_modules.object_id
WHERE name = stored_procedure_name

--The column's name is 'definition'
```

Comment: I thinks you are using Microsoft SQL Server (i see sysobjects). The good way to do this is ask for a data using "syscomments".

Answer (score 0):

You can stored the text into a variable as so:

```
DECLARE @proctext NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @proctext = definition
FROM    sysobjects 
JOIN    sys.sql_modules 
        ON      sysobjects.id = sys.sql_modules.object_id
WHERE name = stored_procedure_name
```

I then recommend playing with the [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx), [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx), [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx), and [RIGHT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) functions of SQL Server to get the rest.

Also, you will most likely want to find the location of `CREATE`, `BEGIN`, and or `END` in the definition when using the functions.

Comment: lol, that's pretty much where I'm at. Not to keen on how to use the substring to get the ALTER and it's contents. If you could give me some idea, it would be great. I couldn't find any examples besides giving numeric values for positions, and that does me no good.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. Haven't tested. Will need to play with the numbers used in SUBSTRING function to get the right result.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([definition], CHARINDEX([definition], 'alter', 0) + 5 , LEN([definition]))
FROM    sysobjects 
JOIN    sys.sql_modules 
        ON      sysobjects.id = sys.sql_modules.object_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select ALTER_DEF=STUFF([definition],PATINDEX('%CREATE%',[definition]),6,'ALTER')
from sys.sql_modules s
inner join sys.procedures p on s.object_id=p.object_id
```

Answer (score -1):

I thinks you are using Microsoft SQL Server (sysobjects).
To do this you need to ask for data "syscomments":

```
select ctext from syscomments where id = object_id(N'procedurename')
```

Ctext contain procedure content!